# Laravel Query Builder, Where based on condition?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have a dropdown to select a parent, which is self-referencing to the Page. I want to limit the results of that dropdown, so that it won't allow me to nest a Page more than one level.

If I edit the 'Son' Page, and the 'Son' has a 'Grandson', than I shouldn't be allowed to select 'Dad' as parent for the son, since it would create a nest that is to deep

*In the folllowing case, When I'm editing the Son record, I shouldn't be able to select Dad as it's parent, since the son has children.*

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | parent_id |  title   |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | NULL      | Dad      |
|  2 | NULL      | Son      |
|  3 | 2         | Grandson |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

*Now in this case, I should be able to select Dad as the parent when I'm editing the Son record, since the Son doesn't have any children*

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | parent_id |  title   |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | NULL      | Dad      |
|  2 | NULL      | Son      |
|  3 | NULL      | Grandson |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

I'm struggling to get my head around this, and on how to wrap this all in the query builder.

#### What I have so far

The following code works if the Son has a Child of it's own, I won't be able to select Dad, which is good. But it fails when there's no children.

It comes down to this: My parent select should also allow pages where parent_id is null to be shown, but only if the current record (Son) doesn't have any children.

Recap: Only show the record if it doesn't occur in any parent_id, so has no children, if it does however no records are to be shown.. If it doesn't, it should show the records where parent_id is null. Is this possible in one query?

```
$query->where('id', '<>', $page->id);
$query->where('parent_id', '<>', $page->id);
```

Comment: So, you want to select record only if there is no children of the record and no parent of the record ?

Comment: Only if the record doesn't occur in any parent_id, so has no children, if it does however no records are to be shown.. If it doesn't, it should show the records where parent_id is null.

Comment: Quite confusing your explanation :D, can you explain in more

Comment: Well I have a dropdown to select a parent, which is self-referencing to the Page. I want to limit the results of that dropdown, so that it won't allow me to nest a Page more then one level. If I edit the 'Son' Page, and the 'Son' has a 'Grandson', than I shouldn't be allowed to select 'Dad' as parent for the son, since it would create a nest that is to deep

Comment: I have added my answer have a try

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the table on itself, as the where-clause is a per-row basis.

Join the table on itself with a left-join, where the ID matches the parent ID. Then select only the rows where the joined table's IDs are null.

```
$pages = DB::table('pages AS p')
            ->leftJoin('pages AS p1', 'p.id', '=', 'p1.parent_id')
            ->where('p.id', '<>', $page->id)
            ->whereNull('p1.id')
            ->select('p.*')
            ->get();
```

- DB fiddle showing the actual query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pwW1aPmYyVqvWjKgXhisbZ/2

Comment: When nobody has parent_id's filled in, this doesn't return any results, while all entities should be able to be selected when there's no parents and children

Comment: Whoops, it's supposed to be a `LEFT JOIN`. Have a look at the revised answer.

Comment: Hmh still not there.. When I edit the "Child", I can select the "Dad" as a parent, although my Child is a parent of Grandchild, so I shouldn't be able to select Dad for that reason. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It's maybe even simpler, If the 'Son', is a parent himself, there should be NO query results, since we can't couple the 'Son' to any other record then..

Comment: So you want that an element that is a parent (of any element) is not included? That's the entire logic?

Comment: It's more complex, Also an element that, if it were to be chosen, would cause more then 1 level deep nesting.. So for example Dad, is not a parent, doesn't have children.. but can't be included when I edit Son, since it would cause the Son's grandson to become level 2 nested.. Hope you understand?

Comment: Your statement there can't be correct - if Dad has no children, then Grandson can't be his grandson! -- So what you want is to select all elements that is a child, or has no parents? I think I achieved what you're trying there, but its not easy to understand what you're describing, to me it seems like you are over-complicating your descriptions :P

Answer (score 1):

You can create parent and children relationship in the Page model.

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Page', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Page', 'parent_id');
}
```

Now, you can check if Page has children or not and the pick up the records with parent id null like this:

```
$pages = Page::where('parent_id', null)->doesntHave('children')->get();
```

This will give you records with parent id null and no children. I hope you understand.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm using the Query Builder, so I don't have access to ->doesntHave()

Comment: @Notflip hmm, Create a model it will ease the process ;)

Comment: It's more complex than that, I have a model, but I'm using this method in Nova, in a function called relatableQuery(), that fills are dropdown with relatable models, I can only filter using the query builder.

Comment: @Notflip ooh, I am not familiar with nova bro. There may be some way

Comment: doesntHave - That's awesome! Never knew that function existed

Comment: @FriendlyCode, There are lot of such tricky functions in laravel ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with query builder sub-query with whereRaw function
Check the code

```
$result = DB::table('parents as p')
    ->whereRaw("parent_id is null and id not in (SELECT parent_id FROM parents WHERE parent_id is not null)")
    ->get();
dd($result);
```

The o/p looks like this 
**1st scenario**

[image]

**2nd Scenario**
[image]

It may help you :)

Comment: In my first scenario I shouldn't be able to select the Dad case, in your example that is what is returned?

Comment: that is the answer i am looking for.:-)

Comment: Okay great :)
then close you question by accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I don't think it is possible to break this to just one line because am like you will have to loop the parent_id column checking whether the current id is in the parent_id column or not:

But not to worry: a different approach would be easier: two separate tables and thus different relationship:

```
Pages model: has one parent
Parents model: belongs to a page
```

With above relationship you it is easy using eloquent to get what has no parent by just checking where has not the given relationship:

Breaking this down:

```
Pages model:

public function parents () {
    return $this->hasOne(Parent::class, 'page_id');
}
```

to parents model:

```
 Parents model:

 protected $fillable = ['page_id'];

 public function pages () {
     return $this->belongsTo(Page::class, 'page_id');
 }
```